# JavaScript: Store first string in for loop in a value?

Tags: javascript

```
var tds = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-cellstyle ms-vb2');
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    if (tds[i].innerHTML.indexOf('Routed') >= 0 && i < tds.length - 1) {
        console.log(tds[i + 1].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

How would I store the first value?
this loop pulls a list of next siblings W1234567,A5364274,G8367483.
Need to store the first found in a value in this case is would be from the list "W1234567"

[image: Console image]

Comment: why not var firstValue = tds[0]?

Comment: It would be nice to have a bit better explanation of your question with a bit more information like the content in `tds` etc

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the *first occurrence*? Is this what you mean?

If so, create a function and pass your parameters in. Return immediately when your condition is true.

```js
function getFirst(className, criteria) {
  var tds = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    if (tds[i].innerHTML.indexOf(criteria) >= 0 && i < tds.length - 1) {
      return tds[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
}

// The target call to highlight.
var targetCell = null;

// The cell with "Routed" in it's text.
var matched = getFirst('ms-cellstyle ms-vb2', 'Routed');

if (matched != null) {
  // Fist sibling is the text of the matched cell, we need the one after that.
  targetCell = matched.nextSibling.nextSibling;
}

if (targetCell != null) {
  targetCell.className += ' found'; // Highlight cell
}
```

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: thin solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.found {
  background: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">Not in OMS</td>
    <td class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">A5364274</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">Routed: Less Than 24 Hours</td>
    <td class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">W1234567</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">Undefined</td>
    <td class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">G8367483</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Side Note:** You can adjust your for loop's condition to coincide with your inner if-condition.

```
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length - 1; i++) {
```

Comment: @ Mr. Polywhirl var first = getFirst('ms-cellstyle ms-vb2', 'Routed'); is only storing the first <td class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">Routed: Less Than 24 Hours</td>    it should be pulling the next string which would be W2343211

Comment: the original displyed a list of strigs A123456, A234443, A2131231

Comment: Do you mean the sibling cell? If so, get the next item via: [`first.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling)...

Comment: Either provide an actual example in your question, or this question will be closed. You are lacking in providing details which will assists us diagnosing your issue.

Comment: attachet notes and image